# How to configure https for Grafana on Windows Server 2022?

Tags: https, config, grafana, windows-server-2022

Pretext:

This is my first solution posted on stack overflow, and I hope it is adequatly formed.
I did not know of whether posting the solution as an answer to a self-raised question, or to make an article on it. Making it an article seemed to be the less appropriate option.

I hope this self-answered question solves your question in one read.

Problem:

**How to configure/setup https for GrafanaEnterprise version 9.2.4.0 on Windows Server 2022 version 10.0.20348?**

Context:

I will follow up this question with the solution that worked for me.
This question is raised, as when I searched the web for answers - I did not find a direct answer and had to gather parts from different solutions I had read up to that point, from different resources that appeared in the Google searches I had made.
The solution to this question will hopefully give a direct solution for any who search for a https solution on a Grafana Windows installation.

I do not know if this is applicable/compatible on/with previous versions of Windows operating systems and or GrafanaEnterprise.

Environment:

- Virtual Machine, Windows Server 2022 version 10.0.20348
- GrafanaEnterprise version 9.2.4.0, standard Windows installer from: https://grafana.com/grafana/download?platform=windows

The solution I tried:

I tried creating self-signed certificates with openssl, "grafana.key" and "grafana.crt", this worked, but when referencing them in Grafana's configuration file "custom.ini" the following error occurred.

The error I encountered:

Windows could not start the Grafana service on Local Computer after uncommenting settings in the Grafana configuration file "custom.ini" under "Server" options. The error message was the following:

> "The service did not return an error. This could be an internal Windows error or an internal service error. If the problem persists, contact your system administrator."

[Image of windows error after attempted restart of Grafana service.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xIsi.png)

Answer (score 4):

This answer contains:

Firstly, in short, a solution to the error after reconfiguring Grafana to use a    supplied .crt and .key file.

Secondly, a guide with all the steps required for the installation of Grafana on Windows Server 2022 with *https*, in my experience.

- Step 1 - Install Grafana
- Step 2 - Install OpenSSL for Windows
- Step 3 - Create selfsigned .crt and .key files as .pem files with
  OpenSSL for Grafana
- Step 4 - Configure Grafana custom.ini file
- Step 5 - Restart and check Grafana
- Bonus - Check that http is disabled

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

**Part 1**

**The error after configuring Grafana's *custom.ini* file to use a supplied .crt and .key file**:

---

**The error - "Windows Could not start the Grafana service on Local Computer."**

[image: Image of Windows error when supplying not .pem files in grafana configuration]

**The solution - how to convert the *.crt* and *.key* files to *.pem* files:**

The Grafana service requires the *.crt* certificate file and the *.key* file to be converted to *.pem* file type.

How to convert a *.crt* file to a *.pem* file with OpenSSL on    Windows:

```
openssl x509 -in DER -out PEM -in grafana.crt -out grafana.crt.pem
```

How to convert a *.key* file to a *.pem* file with OpenSSL on Windows:

```
openssl rsa -in grafana.key -text > grafana.key.pem
```

Note that this conversion of the *.key* writes the private key to the *.pem* as **plain text** and should be replaced by a solution that does not write it as plain text to the *.pem* file.

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

**Part 2**

**A guide to Grafana installation on Windows Server 2022 with Openssl certificate & key in *https* configuration:**

---

**Step 1 - Install Grafana**

- Download Grafana Windows installer file. Follow this link: https://grafana.com/grafana/download?platform=windows
- Start the installation of Grafana by double-clicking on the *grafana-enterprise-9.2.4.windows-amd64.msi* file in your download folder.
- Click *Next > I accept the terms in the License Agreement & Next > Next > Install > Finish*.
- Check that the Grafana service is up and running. Go to your browser and go to *http://localhost:3000/login*, where you should be greeted by the Grafana login GUI:

[image]

**Step 2 - Install OpenSSL for Windows**

- Download OpenSSL for Windows through third party: http://slproweb.com/products.html with the direct download link as http://slproweb.com/download/Win64OpenSSL-3_0_7.msi.
- Start the installation of OpenSSL by double-clicking the installation file *Win64OpenSSL-3_0_7.msi* in your downloads folder.
- Click *I accept the agreement & Next > Next > Next > Next > Install >* Uncheck *One-time $10 donation to Windows OpenSSL > Finish*.

**Step 3 - Create selfsigned *.crt* and *.key* files as *.pem* files with OpenSSL for Grafana**

- Open OpenSSL by searching for it in Windows' search field. An app namned *Win64

  OpenSSL Comand Prompt* should appear in your windows search.

[image]

- Move to the folder where you want to store your certifacte and key
  files by entering in this line. Change the directory to what is fitting for you.

> ```
> cd C:\
> ```

- Create a selfsigned certificate with coupled key file in the current folder
  by entering this. Remember to store the password you have to create
  for the key in a safe location. Also remember to customize the name
  of the files and the days value to your needs.

> ```
> openssl req -x509 -sha256 -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout
> grafana.key -out grafana.crt
> ```

- Convert the .crt file to .pem file.

> ```
> openssl x509 -in DER -out PEM -in grafana.crt -out grafana.crt.pem
> ```

- Convert the .key file to plain text .pem file. This is not optimal and actually a **hazard**. You should try to find an alternative solution in OpenSSL to write the key to a .pem file which is not in plain text. Just remember to check if Grafana can handle the new non-plain text key file.

> ```
> openssl rsa -in grafana.key -text > grafana.key.pem
> ```

- Check that your files are created with this command.

> ```
> dir
> ```

**Step 4 - Configure Grafana *custom.ini* file**

- In file explorer, go to.

> ```
> C:\Program Files\GrafanaLabs\grafana\conf
> ```

- Check that the *default.ini* and *sample.ini* files exist with the dir command.

> ```
> dir
> ```

- Copy the *sample.ini* file and rename the copy to
  *original.sample.ini* file. Do this also for the default.ini file. You are not to edit these files in this guide. Then after the
  copying of the original files you have a backup, if you copy paste
  to the wrong file in the future.
- Copy the *sample.ini* file again and rename it to *https.custom.ini*
  this time.
- Open the *https.custom.ini* file and edit these lines. Change the IP address to the one you are using. You can also change the port number to the one you need. Otherwise, just keep it at 3000.

> ```
> ;protocol = http
> ```

to

> ```
> protocol = https
> ```

&

> ```
> ;root_url = %(protocol)s://%(domain)s:%(http_port)s/
> ```

to

> ```
> root_url = https://1.2.3.4:3000
> ```

&

> ```
> ;cert_file =
>
> ;cert_key =
> ```

to

> ```
> cert_file = C:\grafana.crt.pem
>
> cert_key = C:\grafana.key.pem
> ```

- Save the *https.custom.ini* file.
- Copy the *original.sample.ini* file and rename the copy to
  *original.custom.ini*.

You can in the future copy the content of either the *original.custom.ini*, *https.custom.ini* or any other file you may have made into the *custom.ini* file.

- Now, copy the content of *https.custom.ini* into *custom.ini*, and save
  the latter to apply the settings to the grafana service.

**Step 5 - Restart and check Grafana**

- Open *services.msc* and find the service namned **Grafana**.
- Right click it and select restart.
- Now, go back to your browser and visit the address you entered
  above and you should see a warning. The example I provided above was
  https://1.2.3.4:3000.
- Click the equivalent in your browser of *Advanced > Accept the Risk
  and Continue*.

[image]

Now, you should be at your Grafana's web GUI, **and https is configured!**

**Bonus - Check that http is disabled**

In your browser, try to visit you Grafana address with the http protocol, or simply enter only the IP of your Grafana service in the URL field. You should get the response:

*Client sent an HTTP request to an HTTPS server.*

[image]

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

**An apology**

I want to apologize for the comment having formatting issues, as my account does not have a sufficient score to post more than 8 links in one comment. I had to cut the images.

I will add them at a later date, if my account has a sufficient score then.

---